# exec() works differently in Blender?

Tags: python

Found this example on StackExchange:

```
foo = "bar"
exec(foo + " = 'something else'")
print(bar)
```

Should print:

```
something else
```

Blender (2.73) gives an error that bar is not defined. Can this still be done in Blender?

**EDIT:** This actually works in a blank file. What doesn't work is:

```
class testThis():
    def printMe(self):
        foo = "bar"
        exec(foo + " = 'something else'")
        print(bar)

test = testThis()
test.printMe()
```

Result:

```
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

So I'm not sure if it's Blender related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Stack Overflow, as the problem is with Python itself, not with Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope issue. Your `exec()` does not change the global or method-local scope. Instead, you need to pass two dictionaries to capture the sandboxed global and local scope:

```
class testThis:
    def printMe(self):
        foo = "bar"
        global_scope = {}
        local_scope = {}
        exec(foo + " = 'something else'", global_scope, local_scope)

        print(local_scope)
        # {'bar': 'something else'}

test = testThis()
test.printMe()
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay for marking as correct answer, been on vacation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Official build of Blender come with the latest of Python (*3.4.2* as of Blender 2.73); this means that your code cannot compile/be interpreted since, when moving to version 3.0, Python changed `print` from a *keyword* to a *function*.

Your code should be:

```
foo = "bar"
exec(foo + " = 'something else'")
print(bar) #Print is now a function; must use function call syntax.
```

Comment: You're right, I copied the code from the StackExchange post instead of my code and overlooked the print issue. Still, the result is, that "bar isn't defined".

Comment: @bortran It works fine for me... Are you sure you didn't misspell something, or something like that? Could you post your actual code?

Comment: Works fine for me too in 2.73a on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried the updated code with the class? I copy that 1:1 into a blank text file in 2.73 on Windows and get the error. Just tried again.